# Add mysql range Partition for date column

Tags: mysql

Below is the actual partitioned table.

```
 CREATE TABLE `idea_partition` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `mdn` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `keyword` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `circle` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `mode` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `action` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mobile_type` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `sunsign` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `numerology` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `unsubdate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `user` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pass` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `refid` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `info` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `precharge` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `originator` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `price` double(6,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `renewal_count` int(11) DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`date`),
  UNIQUE KEY `Index_on_mdn_keyword_status` (`mdn`,`keyword`,`status`,`date`),
  KEY `Index_2` (`mdn`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
PARTITION BY RANGE( TO_DAYS(date) ) (
PARTITION rx201201 VALUES LESS THAN( TO_DAYS('2012-01-01 00:00:00') ), 
PARTITION rx201202 VALUES LESS THAN( TO_DAYS('2012-02-01 00:00:00') ), 
PARTITION rx201203 VALUES LESS THAN( TO_DAYS('2012-03-01 00:00:00') ), 
PARTITION rx201204 VALUES LESS THAN( TO_DAYS('2012-04-01 00:00:00') ), 
PARTITION rx201205 VALUES LESS THAN( TO_DAYS('2012-05-01 00:00:00') ), 
PARTITION rx201206 VALUES LESS THAN( TO_DAYS('2012-06-01 00:00:00') ), 
PARTITION rx201207 VALUES LESS THAN( TO_DAYS('2012-07-01 00:00:00') ), 
PARTITION rx201208 VALUES LESS THAN( TO_DAYS('2012-08-01 00:00:00') ), 
PARTITION rx201209 VALUES LESS THAN( TO_DAYS('2012-09-01 00:00:00') ), 
PARTITION rxMORES VALUES LESS THAN (MAXVALUE) );
```

Is it possible to add new partition on an existing range by partition on a date column. Like below -

ALTER TABLE idea_partition partition (TO_DAYS(date)) partition rx201301 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2013-01-01 00:00:00');

It threw me error ..!! But if there is a way to achieve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add more partition by `ALTER Table` like

```
ALTER TABLE TableName ADD PARTITION (PARTITION PartitionName VALUES LESS THAN PartitionVlue);
```

But remember one thing you can not cross partition maximum limit by altering it.

For More Details Read [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table-partition-operations.html) .

Answer (score 0):

well I got the answer I should remove PARTITION rxMORES VALUES LESS THAN (MAXVALUE) first as it tries to fit into that category for any LESS than MAXVALUES. Once I drop the rxMORES partition, it accepts later values on a new partition.

```
mysql> alter table idea_partition drop partition rxMORES; Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.15 sec) Records: 0 Duplicates: 0 Warnings: 0 

mysql> ALTER TABLE idea_partition ADD PARTITION (PARTITION rx201301 VALUES LESS THAN ( TO_DAYS('2013-01-01 00:00:00'))); Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.23 sec) Records: 0 Duplicates: 0 Warnings: 0 mysql>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's safer to use

```
ALTER TABLE ... REORGANIZE PARTITION INTO (...);
```

syntax if don't want to lose data from rxMORES partition.